# android ffmpeg halfninja av_open_input_file returns -2 (no such file or directory)

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have built ffmpeg for Android using the code and method described at

https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

using Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on windows.  I then copied libvideokit.so into the Project\libs\armeabi folder of a Windows copy of the provided projects.  From there I was able to run the ProjectTest from Eclipse on my Android device.  I can see the ffmpeg code being executed but when it gets to the point of opening the input file it gives me the indicated error.  I have noticed some discussion of this problem at

[FFMpeg on Android, undefined references to libavcodec functions, although it is listed on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337833/ffmpeg-on-android-undefined-references-to-libavcodec-functions-although-it-is)

but the solutions have not helped since the file protocol is enabled in this build and I also tried putting "file:" in front of the filepath to no avail.  For completeness I tried setting minimal_featureset=0 to enable all the defaults but this gives me the same error.  Below is a snapshot of the logcat from Eclipse showing the output from Videokit with an extra call to LOGE to display the result from av_open_input_file.  Any suggestions of things to try would be greatly appreciated.

```
10-23 11:57:33.888: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): run() called
10-23 11:57:33.888: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): run passing off to main()
10-23 11:57:33.904: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): main(): registering all modules
10-23 11:57:33.927: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): main(): registered everything
10-23 11:57:33.927: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): main(): initting opts
10-23 11:57:33.943: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): main(): initted opts.
10-23 11:57:33.943: ERROR/Videokit(4830): ffmpeg version N-30996-gf925b24, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
10-23 11:57:33.943: ERROR/Videokit(4830):   built on Oct 21 2011 13:54:03 with gcc 4.4.3
10-23 11:57:33.943: ERROR/Videokit(4830):   configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm5te --enable-armv5te --target-os=linux --disable-stripping --prefix=../output --disable-neon --enable-version3 --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --cc=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --ld=arm-linux-androideabi-ld --extra-cflags='-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated' --disable-everything --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-libx264 --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-protocol=file --enable-hwaccels --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-filter=buffer --enable-filter=buffersink --disable-demuxer=v4l --disable-demuxer=v4l2 --disable-indev=v4l --disable-indev=v4l2 --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -Ivideokit' --extra-ldflags=-L../x264
10-23 11:57:33.943: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): main(): parsing options
10-23 11:57:33.943: DEBUG/Videokit(4830): parse_options has 4 options to parse
10-23 11:57:33.951: ERROR/Videokit(4830): opt_input_file av_open_input_file /mnt/sdcard/fun/snap0000.jpg -2 
10-23 11:57:33.951: ERROR/Videokit(4830): /mnt/sdcard/fun/snap0000.jpg: No such file or directory
10-23 11:57:33.951: ERROR/Videokit(4830): ffmpeg_exit(1) called!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in permissions. On android we have sdcard mounted with system as owner, but without rwx. But ffmpeg checks that:

avformat/file.c:

```
static int file_check(URLContext *h, int mask)
{
    struct stat st;
    int ret = stat(h->filename, &st);
    if (ret < 0)
        return AVERROR(errno);

    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IRUSR ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_READ  : 0;
    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IWUSR ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_WRITE : 0;

    return ret;
}
```

Change this function like this:

```
static int file_check(URLContext *h, int mask)
{
    struct stat st;
    int ret = stat(h->filename, &st);
    if (ret < 0)
        return AVERROR(errno);

    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IRUSR ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_READ  : 0;
    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IRGRP ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_READ  : 0;
    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IROTH ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_READ  : 0;
    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IWUSR ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_WRITE : 0;
    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IWGRP ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_WRITE  : 0;
    ret |= st.st_mode&S_IWOTH ? mask&AVIO_FLAG_WRITE  : 0;


    return ret;
}
```

And rebuild your ffmpeg. And that`s it!

Comment: This isn't fixing the problem for me - is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Actually, this and switching to ndk-r8 from ndk-r5c solved it.

Comment: I don't know if you found this issue yourself, but anyway thank you for sharing. You finally got me out of a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have the same issue while compiling FFMpeg with this version :
http://www.roman10.net/?p=389

And enabling all that can be enabled ( getting rid of the --disable-everything option ).

If you have some idea, I'm interested :)

Edit :
On the HalfNinja site, here is what is written :
"...at the moment I’m having some problems with input files (I think most inputs are fine but it doesn’t recognise JPEG sequences)."
:(

Comment: I'll let you know if I figure it out.  The info you provided is good to know.