# Transcoding Mp4 video on Android with FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I've compiled FFMPEG binary from [Bambuser project](http://bambuser.com/opensource) (refer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk)) and have pushed binary and .so files to application directory.

But when I try running FFMPEG with input file, it always complains file not found.

```
1|root@android:/data/data/com.bambuser.broadcaster # ls                        
cache           libavcodec.so   libavfilter.so  libswscale.so
ffmpeg          libavcore.so    libavformat.so  tutorial.mp4
lib             libavdevice.so  libavutil.so
1|root@android:/data/data/com.bambuser.broadcaster # ./ffmpeg -i tutorial.mp4 out.mp4                                                              
FFmpeg version UNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May  8 2012 10:11:37 with gcc 4.4.3
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --sysroot=/home/tarandeep/tools/android-ndk/platforms/android-3/arch-arm --soname-prefix=/data/data/com.bambuser.broadcaster/lib/ --enable-shared --disable-symver --enable-small --optimization-flags=-O2 --disable-everything --enable-encoder=mpeg2video --enable-encoder=nellymoser --prefix=../build/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp' --extra-ldflags=
  libavutil     50.34. 0 / 50.34. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 0 /  0.16. 0
  libavcodec    52.99. 1 / 52.99. 1
  libavformat   52.88. 0 / 52.88. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 2 / 52. 2. 2
  libavfilter    1.69. 0 /  1.69. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
tutorial.mp4: No such file or directory
```

I've tried placing file in /sdcard and other locations, I always get same output

Comment: Did you try specifying full path names?

Comment: yes. Both relative, absolute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8940434/112212

Comment: Hmm. I had made all files (including binary, so, video files) 777. It shouldn't matter isn't it?

Comment: Try strace'ing it to see what it's really passing to open() or try instrumenting the code that prints that error and make sure it really means file not found, vs. being sloppy about applying that to other sorts of errors.

Answer (score 3):

i downloaded the code 'Archive for client versions 1.3.7 to 1.6.0.'. I found that in the build.sh file there's the line `FLAGS="$FLAGS --disable-everything"` that disable all the protocols for loading a file (file, http, etc.). commenting this line or enable the protocols that you need allow you to load correctly the file.